# Matching a Slater-type wavefunction with 6-31G basis set for first and second row atoms Gaussian basis set

Tags: computational-chemistry

I am trying to match the slater wavefunction with 6-31G basis set for first and second row elements. I have matche hydrogen, helium and lithium atom 1s orbital with Slater wavefunction using STO-6G but unable to match with 6-31G basis set.

Comment: What you mean exactly by matching? You must review how Slater Type Orbitals (STOs) and Gaussian Type Orbitals (GTOs) are build. You must  consider what type of orbitals are used to describe the radial part of the orbital, and  distinguish between primitive and contracted orbitals. Basically, with STOs you get only an orbital of each type of the "available" orbitals (minimal basis set).

Comment: continue...  In the case of GTOs you get and extended basis set. For 6-31G b. s. (split valence b.s.), you get one orbital for each of the internal electrons but you get two orbitals of each type ($\mathrm{s}$, $\mathrm{p_x}$, $\mathrm{p_y}$, $\mathrm{p_z}$,...) for the valence electron orbitals.